# Create a Dataframe with lists of different sizes

Tags: python, pandas

Changed to explain it better:

```
A = ['one',None,None,None]
B = [None,'two',None,None],
C = [None,None,'three','Four']
```

If i create a Dataframe I would get:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A,
                   'B':B,
                   'C':C
})
df     
       A    B       C
0   one     None    None
1   None    two     None
2   None    None    three
3   None    None    Four
```

But I want a DataFrame similar to the Expected Output below
Expected Output:

```
       A    B       C
0   one     two     three
1   None    None    four
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: df1 is the expected output i'm looking for

Comment: I'm confused as to *why* that should be the desired output.  Yes there are quite a few ways to turn `df` into `df1`, but what is the rule you are following?

Comment: It looks like you are sorting by the number that each string describes and removing rows that are all `None`

Comment: There isn't any rule so as, I have taken a  database schema pivoted the schema with columns = table_name and values = column_name and I got None values for column_names for each table in a column, I just made theabove df for simplicity

Comment: `df.bfill().iloc[[0,-1]]`? @S_Ymln

Comment: @HarvIpan this might be helpful to achieve specifically for my df but i'm looking for general purpose to work on bigger dataframe. Instead of suggesting what you said i can just simply create a Dataframe if my goal is to achieve that small piece

Comment: But you have not provided a general rule to follow.  Please read about how to create an [mcve] before asking future questions, as you are more likely to find help.

Comment: Its really hard to help you without knowing what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Everyone. Sorry that I'm not clear. I just want to explore PANDAS more. I know this isn't going to be useful in any of the real world situations but i'm curious. Below is the way I'm able to achieve what I was looking for. Please let me know if there are any other efficient ways of achieving the same.

```
a= df['A'].dropna().unique()
b= df['B'].dropna().unique()
c= df['C'].dropna().unique()
df_abc = pd.DataFrame({'A' : dict(zip(range(len(a)),a)),
                       'B': dict(zip(range(len(b)),b)),
                       'C' :dict(zip(range(len(c)),c))
                      })
df_abc

    A   B   C
0   one two three
1   NaN NaN Four
```